# raphaeljs and freetransform with the combination of clip-path

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael, transform

i am using Raphael and Elberts FreeTransform Plugin.
this is what i tried yet [MyWork](http://jsfiddle.net/Lg2Gy/28/)

My clip path works until i do not translate or rotate the set of rectangles, just after rotation or translation it stop working properly.
I want those rectangles inside the boundary of path, as soon as they go outside they should disappear.
The answer to why i am using javascript(manually) not Raphael for clippath, is , Raphael only supports clip rect.
i need your help to sort out this one.

thanks in advance

> Update:1
>   [My Work 2](http://jsfiddle.net/Lg2Gy/31/)
>   I solve it for translation case but in rotation case it still disturbs all the set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a new `g` tag(group) and moving all the elements to that group and then applying `clip-path` to g tag works. ClipPath doesn't recognize `transform` of attribute of element if applied to individual elems. So it should be wrapped in `g` for this.

[It is applied Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Lg2Gy/41/)

Answer (score 1):

Please check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/UGukL/

I have tried the problem with clip, it was not working. So decided to work with mask.
            Also i havn't implemented the drag but keept buttons for translate and rotate.
            Now the masking is working fine for both rotation and translation.

Comment: thanks dear, nice effort! Would you explain me the difference between mask and clip-path?

Comment: The filled area of an mask, exposes the masked object. Whereas the clip behaves in opposite way.
But both are non destructive ways.

Comment: Hi, the mask you applied, work with the g tag(group) only. If i use it with the rect it doesn't work

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/UGukL/5/ the same thing works with clip-path if g tag applied, otherwise not.. it means masking and clippath both having the same problem in rotation case. can not be applicable to an individual element, but applicable to g tag i.e., groups